# How to reference environment variables from .env file with cross-env?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, package.json, cross-env

I have to set node environment variables using `cross-env` in package.json but the values are in a `.env` file.

I've tried the following formats but none has worked.

```
cross-env API_KEY=%API_KEY% && ...
```

```
cross-env API_KEY=$API_KEY && ...
```

```
cross-env %API_KEY% && ...
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be using [env-cmd](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd) instead

Answer (score 9):

[cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) is used to set environment variables inline when running node commands.

> cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.config.js

However when populating environment variables from .env files you'll need to use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) or similar.

It's common to have a separate .env file for each environment (.env.development, .env.production...). To configure this with dotenv you need to run `dotenv.config` at the root of your project, to pick the right .env file.

```
dotenv.config({
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, `${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`)
});
```

Comment: `env-cmd` also supports a `-f` option for use in `scripts`

Comment: Did you mean `development.env` and `production.env`, because `${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env` in `path.resolve` !?